# Gradle dependencies: package does not exist

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, dependency-injection

I know this has been asked multiple times but the questions have multiple answers.

I'm trying to use a Java package that's a dependency of my dependency. Let's say I've built this gradle project called "ee_tools". And that has a dependency called "my_models", which has a package called "com.mycompany.my_models.db". So in the ee_tools project build.gradle, I've got

```
dependencies {
   // My stuff
   implementation group: "com.mycompany", name: "my_models", version: "1.0.0"
}
```

Then in my current project, I've got

```
dependencies {
   // My stuff
  implementation group: "com.mycompany", name: "ee_tools", version: "1.0.0"
```

Shouldn't this mean that the public classes in my_models are accessible through ee_tools to my current project? Gradle was able to find both in my artifactory instance. And the `gradle dependencies` command shows ee_tools under the compileClasspath, implementation, and testCompileClasspath trees, but not with its children dependencies. It also shows up in the runtimeClasspath and testRuntimeClasspath trees *with* its children dependencies, including my_models.

I am also able to see that package inside the jar on the left side of IntelliJ, under the "External Libraries" tree, along with some classes.

But when I try to use the my_models package in my current project, IntelliJ can't find it and it fails a `gradle build` with the error
`error: package com.company.my_models.db does not exist`

It can't find any package in that dependency. What gives? Am I declaring the dependencies incorrectly? Or is this a gap between the gradle binary in my command line vs IntellJ and gradlew?

Answer (score 0):

If ee_tools depends on my_models, then your gradle file in ee_tools should be like

```
implementation project(path: ":path:to:my_models", configuration: 'default')
```

:path:to:my_models is defined in settings.gradle in project root path like this:

```
include ':path:to:my_models'
```

Comment: There is no way to do this purely in the build.gradle files?

Comment: No. build.gradle file could do things during building period only. setting.build file could organize dirs and modules.

Comment: I'm not trying to set a directory. All I want to do is let my dependency expose one of its dependencies to my project. Essentially, I'm the grandparent, and I'm trying to get the grandchild through the child. Running `gradle dependencies` shows the child, but doesn't expand its tree, so its dependencies are not available.

Comment: As far as I know, setting a dir is the only way :(